# NHibernate ISessionFactory breaks my assembly, why?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

When I have the following bit of code in my C# Class Library, it totally breaks the library for everything else.

```
namespace DesktopOCA.Infastructure
{
    public class NHibernateHelper
    {
        private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

For example this is also in that project:

```
namespace DesktopOCA.Infastructure
{
    public static class RegionNames
    {
        public const string MainRegion = "MainRegion";
    }
}
```

When I dont include the

```
private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
```

line everything else in my solution can see RegionNames.MainRegion. But as soon as I make any reference to an ISessionFactory, it breaks. That particular class library still compiles fine. I can add it as a reference in other parts of the project, but it's like there is nothing there.

I get the error

```
Error   40  The name 'RegionNames' does not exist in the current context
```

Any help would really be appreciated here, this seems really weird to me.

Comment: This sounds like one of those bizarro "Clean and Rebuild" type situations.  Have you tried looking at the class library DLL with Reflector?

Answer (score 1):

Static classes can only contain static members.  Either move the static keyword from the `RegionNames` class to the MainRegion member or get rid of static altogether.  It depends or what you're doing with that class.

See the MSDN doc for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(VS.80).aspx

edit: also, if you want to keep MainRegion as static, you'll have to change const to readonly.

edit2: I was using Reflector today to look at System.Data.Common.ADP and noticed `const` without the static keyword within the static class.  The last section "Static Members" of the above link says:

> Although a field cannot be declared as
>   static const, a const field is
>   essentially static in its behavior. It
>   belongs to the type, not to instances
>   of the type. Therefore, const fields
>   can be accessed by using the same
>   ClassName.MemberName notation that is
>   used for static fields. No object
>   instance is required.

It doesn't, however, say whether this works within a static class and is fairly ambiguous in its wording: there cannot be static members, const cannot be static, but that const can be accessed as if it is static.